# Running Angular 13 and .NET Project Locally on Tablet

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a project using Angular 13 and .NET, and I want to run it locally on my tablet. However, I am facing some difficulties. I am able to run the project on my computer successfully, but I cannot achieve the same on my tablet. I need assistance with this.

Here are the steps I followed to run the project on my tablet within the same network:

I successfully ran my .NET and Angular project on my computer and found out my IP address.

I entered my computer's IP address and the port number on which the Angular project is running into the browser on my tablet.

However, I encountered an error saying "Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory," and I couldn't start the project on my tablet.

I also tried running the project in production mode and adjusting Node.js memory limits, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I kindly request your assistance. Do you have any suggestions or guidance on how I can run my project on my tablet? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I cleared the cookies but unfortunately it didn't work again :(
now I will share two pictures, the first picture is the api request I sent from the computer, the second picture is the api request I sent from the tablet

Request I sent from my computer : https://ibb.co/dk1MvZN

Request sent from tablet : https://ibb.co/1KK5ntZ

Comment: Any updates about the issue ?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to return due to my busy schedule. I haven't tried your suggestion right now, I will try and give feedback when I am available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an environment variable through a Windows PowerShell terminal.

**Type the below command and press Enter:**

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

Comment: This worked, it worked, but this time it doesn't send requests to the api. when I try it from the computer it works fine, but when I try it from the tablet it doesn't send requests to the api

Comment: Hi @ErenAkgöz, [could you try this in browser with ipad or something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvfg.png). And anohter suggestion is, try to install software which can monitor the network trace. It will help us investigate the issue deeper.

Comment: I tried it on Windows PC, Iphone Phone and Android Tablet but unfortunately it only worked on Windows PC.   this photo is sent when I send a request from the tablet, there are differences in the request request headers according to the computer 
 https://ibb.co/1KK5ntZ

Comment: Hi @ErenAkgöz, [Try this in your iphone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/web-inspector/id1584825745), it could help us to check the network trace. I guess maybe the api url is wrong when you are using the mobile device.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz We need more details to verify it. Or maybe the cookie cause the issue, who knows.

Comment: Şuan elimde maalesef bir iphone yok ama hataları kurcalarken şöyle bir hata buldum : "[Exception: DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseXML' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'document' (was 'text'). at XMLHttpRequest.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:3:28)]"

Comment: Hi @ErenAkgöz I saw the error message, could you use the English when you send the comment, tks

Comment: I'm very sorry, it was a momentary lapse of judgment :) . Unfortunately, I don't have an iphone at the moment, but I found a bug like this while messing around with bugs:

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Pls share the snippet code about the error message, I want check how you send the http request in you angular project.

Comment: The error I print to the console screen https://ibb.co/BrmBv0g

Comment: I cleared the cookies but unfortunately it didn't work again :( 
now I will share two pictures, the first picture is the api request I sent from the computer, the second picture is the api request I sent from the tablet 

Request I sent from my computer : https://ibb.co/dk1MvZN

Request sent from tablet : https://ibb.co/1KK5ntZ

Comment: Hi @ErenAkgöz If using other PCs access http://192.168.1.20:4200 in the LAN, is everything normal?

Comment: @ErenAkgöz I think we are getting closer to the truth, please stay online and I will try to help you. If I want to give up and I will let you know.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Try to excute `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20`. And tell me the result.

Comment: The IP address was successfully added, but this time it broke on both the computer and the tablet :)

Comment: netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20 after writing this code I tried to run it with ng serve and it gave an error.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Have you try to excute it with administrator.

Comment: yes, I ran it as a directive and deleted it using the command "netsh http delete iplisten" it started working on the computer but still the same on the tablet: